Type mismatch in Go generics with mixed untyped arguments
func sum[T int | float64](a, b T) T {
    fmt.Println("Type of a: ", reflect.TypeOf(a))
    fmt.Println("Type of b: ", reflect.TypeOf(b))
    return a + b
}

type Pair[K, V any] struct {
    key K
    val V
}

func main() {
    p := Pair[int, float64]{key: 10, val: 10.2}
    fmt.Println(sum(10, 10.2))
    fmt.Println(sum(10, -40))
    fmt.Println(sum(20, 20.100909999988888))
    fmt.Println(sum(p.key, p.val))
}

When executing the Go language code this line fmt.Println(sum(p.key, p.val)), an error occurs. Could someone explain exactly why this is happening?
For the statement fmt.Println(sum(p.key, p.val)), I was expecting it to print the sum of the two numbers.

I see two things worth noting in your example:

one point about how literal constants are interpreted (and given a type) by the go compiler
one point about how a generic definition int|float64 should be interpreted



there is a trick when go deals with literal constants: they do not have a hard set type:

see the Constants section in the language specification (emphasis mine):

A constant may be given a type explicitly by a constant declaration or conversion, or implicitly when used in a variable declaration or an assignment statement or as an operand in an expression.

As an illustration, see: https://go.dev/play/p/uq__T_6HYkM
    // in the following statement:
    // '10' and '10.2' are assigned a suitable type (float64) from this expression:
    fmt.Println(sum(10, 10.2))
    // Output:
    // Type of a:  float64
    // Type of b:  float64
    // 20.2

    // in the following 3 lines however:
    // '10' is given a type at 'x := 10' expression -> int
    // '10.2' is given a type at 'y := 10.2' expression -> float64
    x := 10
    y := 10.2

    // and the following line fails to compile:
    // fmt.Println(sum(x, y))
    // compilation error:
    // in call to sum, type float64 of y does not match inferred type int for T


the second point is about how func sum[T int | float64](a, b T) T is interpreted:

it means sum is one of:

func sum(a, b int) int
or func sum(a, b float64) float64

but when you use typed values, you cannot have a mix of both

My guess is you got mislead by 1., and probably expected 2.

When you write a generic function such as:
func sum[T int | float64](a, b T) T

you declare both parameters a and b to have the same type T.
The constraint int | float64 permits T to be either int or float64. But whichever that is, the parameters a and b both have the same one type.
In other words, your function sum can only be called with two int arguments or two float64 arguments. For more information about this, see my answer here: Difference between any/interface{} as constraint vs. type of argument?
When you call
p := Pair[int, float64]{key: 10, val: 10.2}
sum(p.key, p.val)

the struct fields have two different types int and float64 as per your instantiation Pair[int, float64], therefore type inference fails.
So why does sum(10, 10.2) compile?
When a generic function is called with only untyped arguments, starting from Go 1.21 type inference follows the rules of constant operations:

If multiple untyped constant arguments of different kinds (such as an untyped int and an untyped floating-point constant) are passed to parameters with the same (not otherwise specified) type parameter type, instead of an error, now type inference determines the type using the same approach as an operator with untyped constant operands

And this approach with untyped constant operands is specified as:

If the untyped operands of a binary operation (other than a shift) are of different kinds, the result is of the operand's kind that appears later in this list: integer, rune, floating-point, complex.

The list is literally what appears after the colon in that sentence:
integer, rune, floating-point, complex
The literal 10 is an untyped constant of kind "integer", 10.2 is of kind "floating-point", which appears after "integer" in the list above, therefore type inference determines the type parameter T to be float64.
At this point, the argument 10 can be assigned to a parameter of type T = float64, and type inference succeeds.
